# remove rows based on value in list entry of a column

Tags: python, pandas, list

I'm looking to remove rows based on some specific conditions and can't seem to figure out how to do that. My dataframe `groads` looks like:

```
     bridge tunnel          x                          y
262732  F     F     [4.9703655, 4.9720589]  [52.8451222, 52.8450346]
262733  F     F     [4.9739675, 4.9741636]  [52.8442294, 52.8442168]
262734  F     F     [4.8682209, 4.8681081]  [52.3388499, 52.3388448]
262735  F     F     [4.8681081, 4.8680897]  [52.3388448, 52.338844]
262736  F     F     [4.8682725, 4.8682432, 4.8682209]   [52.3388522, 52.3388509, 52.3388499]
```

As you can guess these are coordinates, but I want to remove the full row if one the coordinates in the list of an entry is higher or lower than certain values. If I were to save these values in a new list I would use something like

`newlist = [coord_list for coord_list in groads['x'] if coord_list[0] > 5 or coord_list[0] < 4.8]`

Essentially this keeps the values I want but I'd also like to delete the rows (or keep the relevant rows) of the dataframe that correspond with this criteria. Does anyone know how to do this? Help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca nselect first lists in column `x` by indexing by `str[0]` and then get values by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#changed data sample for test
print (df)
       bridge tunnel                                  x  \
262732      F      F             [5.9703655, 4.9720589]   
262733      F      F             [3.9739675, 4.9741636]   
262734      F      F             [4.8682209, 4.8681081]   
262735      F      F             [4.8681081, 4.8680897]   
262736      F      F  [4.8682725, 4.8682432, 4.8682209]   

                                           y  
262732              [52.8451222, 52.8450346]  
262733              [52.8442294, 52.8442168]  
262734              [52.3388499, 52.3388448]  
262735               [52.3388448, 52.338844]  
262736  [52.3388522, 52.3388509, 52.3388499] 


df1 = df[df['x'].str[0].between(4.8, 5, inclusive=False)]
print (df1)
       bridge tunnel                                  x  \
262734      F      F             [4.8682209, 4.8681081]   
262735      F      F             [4.8681081, 4.8680897]   
262736      F      F  [4.8682725, 4.8682432, 4.8682209]   

                                           y  
262734              [52.3388499, 52.3388448]  
262735               [52.3388448, 52.338844]  
262736  [52.3388522, 52.3388509, 52.3388499]
```